# Android TextView make http and custom scheme urls clickable

Tags: android, android-intent, linkify, custom-scheme-url

I'm creating an android app and have defined an activity as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.scheme.app.MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:host="invite"
            android:scheme="schemeapp" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When hitting the url ***"schemeapp://invite"*** the user will be taken to MainActivity.

I have a textView with the following content:

```
textView.setText("Testing custom scheme - schemeapp://invite with http http://www.LMNGTFY.com");
```

I need to make the web url (http://www.LMNGTFY.com) as well as the custom url (schemeapp://invite) clickable.

**What I've already tried:**

```
String text = "Testing custom scheme - schemeapp://invite with http http://www.LMNGTFY.com";
textView.setText(text);
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS | Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.ALL);
Pattern urlDetect = Pattern.compile("(schemeapp):\\/\\/([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)");
Matcher matcher = urlDetect.matcher(text);
String scheme = null;

while (matcher.find()) {
    String customSchemedUrl = matcher.group(0);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(customSchemedUrl);
    scheme = uri.getScheme();
    break;
}

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(scheme)) {
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, urlDetect, scheme);
}
```

If I remove the following line of code to detect web urls, the custom scheme url works:

```
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS | Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.ALL);
```

If I try to add http as a custom scheme url, the http urls aren't clickable.

**EDIT: Clarification**

I cannot use HTML since, user input will also be displayed on the TextView and needs to be linked.

Can you please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one option:

```
final Spanned html = Html.fromHtml("Testing custom scheme - <a href='schemeapp://invite'>schemeapp://invite</a> with http http://www.LMNGTFY.com";);

helpText.setText(html);
helpText.setMovementMethod(new LinkMovementMethod());
```

Comment: thanks, that would work, but I cannot put html, the textview will also show input from the users, so they won't be using HTML tags.

Comment: you could preprocess the text before then like userinput.replace("schemeapp://.*..","<a href= ..

Comment: testing the same on our iPhone app, since the content is cross-platform ..

Comment: Sure but you can do the preprocessing on android before setting to the textview

Comment: I had to do some processing, but this was the only way to make it work in all scenarios. @ligi appreciate the effort mate.